# postgres double precision

Tags: postgresql

```
select round(product_qty * 100) - product_qty as test, 
       id, product_qty 
from stock_move 
where product_id=63 
  and state='done' 
  and id=45058;
```

```
        test         |  id   | product_qty 
54.45                | 45058 |        0.55
(1 ligne)
```

```
select round(product_qty * 100) - (product_qty*100) as test, 
       id, 
       product_qty 
from stock_move 
where product_id=63 
  and state='done' 
  and id=45058;
```

```
        test         |  id   | product_qty 

 -7.105427357601e-15 | 45058 |        0.55
(1 ligne)
```

can somebody explain me these results?

Comment: Could you please tell us what you're trying to ask?

Comment: Calculations on doubles are subject to rounding errors, not much can be done about it.  Lots of articles treating that subject here on SO, use search

Comment: Guys, this is a real question (about double precision inaccuracy), but has been answered by fvu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating-point representations like double precision fields in pg are by their very nature subject to rounding errors.  [This paper](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) gives a good mathematical introduction.

How you deal with these rounding errors depends on a bit on your application, and varies between:

- just living with them eg by sort of ignoring them - format that result as %.2f and the error will become invisible.  Just make sure you understand *all* the consequences of that choice!!
- switching datatypes to something that by design is not subject to rounding issues - check out pg's [money](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-money.html) type and the [exact numeric types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-numeric.html).

The latter should be the preferred approach especially in contexts where your application handles money.

Comment: +1 for linking _"What Every Computer Scientist Should Know.."_ :)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting those results because `product_qty*100` has different IEEE-754 binary representation than `round(product_qty * 100)`:

```
without round : 100000001001011100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
with round    : 100000001001011100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

It's easy to see that 55 should be represented as 1,71875 * 2<sup>5</sup> (as in with round), but due to floating point arithmetic `product_qty*100` is slightly different.

If you want to still live with floating point number, then I recommend to read "What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic" paper, or just switch to `numeric` type with arbitrary precision.